# Make command taking too much time while installing gcc via brew

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I have installed Xcode on my mac. However, installing gcc via the command `brew install gcc` is too time-consuming.

The issue with the brew installation is that `make` is taking hours to run and even then does not get completed.

Comment: Did you try the commands `brew doctor` and `brew update` separately? Also, you may check your internet speed with the following command, which should take less than one minute to complete: `curl -o /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip` Or if you don't have curl try with: `wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how it goes. GCC is a big program, and takes a *long* time to build.

But! If you install the Xcode *Command Line Tools*, not just Xcode itself, then you can install `gcc` from the binary "bottle" file instead of building it yourself. Do this at the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

and say yes to the dialog that pops up. When it's finished, try doing `brew install gcc` again, and you should get a nice, quick binary installation.

Comment: Now that's a problem. As far as I know, `xcode-select` is present in `/usr/bin/` in every (non-broken) macOS installation for the last several years. Maybe you have a `$PATH` issue in your shell configuration?